# C# Variable Doesn't Change When The Calculation is Performed

Tags: c#, variables, double, console-application

I'm creating a simple calculator for my C# class and having some trouble with the final calculations.

I've declared my variables and I'm using simple if then statements for the order. My problem is, after I've defined my variables, the information they contain doesn't change when the calculation is performed, they simply just output zero as defined by the original value instead of outputting the new amount from the if statement (`TotalCost`, `Tax`, `TotalWithTax`).

I've input different numbers in place of the zero and the formulas work, it's just that the value never changes to what I have stated in the

1. If statements. Is it not possible to adjust the value of a variable from within a if statement?
2. What is another possible way to go about this if that is the case?

Trying to keep it simple as I'm not really proficient with console programming.

```
        string SizeName = "";
        double SizeCost = 0;
        string ToppingName = "";
        double ToppingCost = 0;
        double TotalCost = (SizeCost + ToppingCost);
        double Tax = (TotalCost*0.085);
        double TotalWithTax = (TotalCost + Tax);

        //Print a greeting message.
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Central Pizza Parlor!");

        //Ask if the customer would like to order a pizza.
        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to order a pizza today? Enter y for Yes or n for No.");
        string Order = Console.ReadLine();

        //Start the order if answer is Yes, if not, then exit the program.
        if (Order == "y")
        {
            //Continue with order.
            Console.WriteLine("Great! Let's get started, please pick the size of your pizza:");
            Console.WriteLine("1 - Small  $5.00");
            Console.WriteLine("2 - Medium $7.00");
            Console.WriteLine("3 - Large  $9.00");

            //Get pizza size for order.
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number for the pizza size you would like.");
            string sizeAsAString = Console.ReadLine();
            int size = Convert.ToInt32(sizeAsAString);


            //Use If Else statement to set the variable value for SizeCost.
            if (size == 1)
            {
                SizeCost = 5.0;
                SizeName = ("Small");
            }
            else if (size == 2)
            {
                SizeCost = 7.0;
                SizeName = ("Medium");
            }
            else if (size == 3)
            {
                SizeCost = 9.0;
                SizeName = ("Large");
            }

            //Have Customer select toppings.
            Console.WriteLine("Please select which topping you would like on your pizza.");
            ;
            Console.WriteLine("1 - Pepperoni     $2.00");
            Console.WriteLine("2 - Ham           $2.00");
            Console.WriteLine("3 - Onions        $1.00");
            Console.WriteLine("4 - Mushrooms     $1.00");
            Console.WriteLine("5 - Green Peppers $1.00");

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number for the corresponding topping you would like.");
            string toppingAsAString = Console.ReadLine();
            int topping = Convert.ToInt32(toppingAsAString);


            //Use If Else statement to set the variable value for ToppingCost.
            if (topping == 1) 
            {
                ToppingCost = 2.0;
                ToppingName = ("Pepperoni");
            }
            else if (topping == 2)
            {
                ToppingCost = 2.0;
                ToppingName = ("Ham");
            }
            else if (topping == 3)
            {
                ToppingCost = 1.0;
                ToppingName = ("Onions");
            }
            else if (topping == 4)
            {
                ToppingCost = 1.0;
                ToppingName = ("Mushrooms");
            }
            else if (topping == 5)
            {
                ToppingCost = 1.0;
                ToppingName = "Green Peppers";
            }

            //Display order details.
            Console.WriteLine("Here are the details for your order.");
            Console.WriteLine("Thank you for your business!");
            Console.WriteLine("You can pick up your pizza in 25 minutes!");

            //Show current time of order.
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine("Time Ordered: "+now+" ");

            //Show Current time of order with additional 25 minutes for pickup.
            DateTime pickup = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(25);
            Console.WriteLine("Pick Up At: "+pickup+" ");

            //Output Pizza Size.
            Console.WriteLine("Size: " +SizeName+ "  ");

            //OutPut Topping name.
            Console.WriteLine("Topping: " +ToppingName+ " ");

            Console.WriteLine("---------------");

            //Output total price of size and topping chosen.
            Console.WriteLine("Pizza Price: $ "+TotalCost+" ");

            //Output tax amount.
            Console.WriteLine("Tax: $" +Tax+ " ");

            //Output total price with tax.
            Console.WriteLine("Total Price: $" +TotalWithTax+ "  ");

        }
        else 
        {
            //Exit the program because the customer does not want to order a pizza.
            Console.WriteLine("Alright, have a great day!");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint at `if (Order == "y")` and step through the code to see what its doing.

Comment: Getting an exception error at **int size = Convert.ToInt32(sizeAsAString);**, not sure why though, shouldn't it be converting the string to an integer format for the if statement which is the next step. Not sure why it still works with this error when the program is ran though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your calcualtions are at the top(in declaration). Performing your calculations with ***defaults*** will not output desired result.

```
double TotalCost = (SizeCost + ToppingCost);
double Tax = (TotalCost*0.085);
double TotalWithTax = (TotalCost + Tax);
```

Move these calcualtions to bottom (before outputting).

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {       
          string SizeName = "";
        double SizeCost = 0;
        string ToppingName = "";
        double ToppingCost = 0;
        double TotalCost =0;
        double Tax = 0;
        double TotalWithTax = 0;

        //Print a greeting message.
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Central Pizza Parlor!");

        //Ask if the customer would like to order a pizza.
        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to order a pizza today? Enter y for Yes or n for No.");
        string Order = Console.ReadLine();

        //Start the order if answer is Yes, if not, then exit the program.
        if (Order == "y")
        {
            //Continue with order.
            Console.WriteLine("Great! Let's get started, please pick the size of your pizza:");
            Console.WriteLine("1 - Small  $5.00");
            Console.WriteLine("2 - Medium $7.00");
            Console.WriteLine("3 - Large  $9.00");

            //Get pizza size for order.
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number for the pizza size you would like.");
            string sizeAsAString = Console.ReadLine();
            int size = Convert.ToInt32(sizeAsAString);


            //Use If Else statement to set the variable value for SizeCost.
            if (size == 1)
            {
                SizeCost = 5.0;
                SizeName = ("Small");
            }
            else if (size == 2)
            {
                SizeCost = 7.0;
                SizeName = ("Medium");
            }
            else if (size == 3)
            {
                SizeCost = 9.0;
                SizeName = ("Large");
            }

            //Have Customer select toppings.
            Console.WriteLine("Please select which topping you would like on your pizza.");
            ;
            Console.WriteLine("1 - Pepperoni     $2.00");
            Console.WriteLine("2 - Ham           $2.00");
            Console.WriteLine("3 - Onions        $1.00");
            Console.WriteLine("4 - Mushrooms     $1.00");
            Console.WriteLine("5 - Green Peppers $1.00");

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number for the corresponding topping you would like.");
            string toppingAsAString = Console.ReadLine();
            int topping = Convert.ToInt32(toppingAsAString);


            //Use If Else statement to set the variable value for ToppingCost.
            if (topping == 1) 
            {
                ToppingCost = 2.0;
                ToppingName = ("Pepperoni");
            }
            else if (topping == 2)
            {
                ToppingCost = 2.0;
                ToppingName = ("Ham");
            }
            else if (topping == 3)
            {
                ToppingCost = 1.0;
                ToppingName = ("Onions");
            }
            else if (topping == 4)
            {
                ToppingCost = 1.0;
                ToppingName = ("Mushrooms");
            }
            else if (topping == 5)
            {
                ToppingCost = 1.0;
                ToppingName = "Green Peppers";
            }

             TotalCost = (SizeCost + ToppingCost);
            Tax = (TotalCost*0.085);
            TotalWithTax = (TotalCost + Tax);

            //Display order details.
            Console.WriteLine("Here are the details for your order.");
            Console.WriteLine("Thank you for your business!");
            Console.WriteLine("You can pick up your pizza in 25 minutes!");

            //Show current time of order.
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine("Time Ordered: "+now+" ");

            //Show Current time of order with additional 25 minutes for pickup.
            DateTime pickup = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(25);
            Console.WriteLine("Pick Up At: "+pickup+" ");

            //Output Pizza Size.
            Console.WriteLine("Size: " +SizeName+ "  ");

            //OutPut Topping name.
            Console.WriteLine("Topping: " +ToppingName+ " ");

            Console.WriteLine("---------------");

            //Output total price of size and topping chosen.
            Console.WriteLine("Pizza Price: $ "+TotalCost+" ");

            //Output tax amount.
            Console.WriteLine("Tax: $" +Tax+ " ");

            //Output total price with tax.
            Console.WriteLine("Total Price: $" +TotalWithTax+ "  ");


        }
        else 
        {
            //Exit the program because the customer does not want to order a pizza.
            Console.WriteLine("Alright, have a great day!");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();


    }
}
```

Fiddler [Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/b98qtd)

Answer (score 0):

You set TotalCost before changing the Values of SizeCost or ToppingCost.

Move these lines

```
double TotalCost = (SizeCost + ToppingCost);
double Tax = (TotalCost*0.085);
double TotalWithTax = (TotalCost + Tax);
```

to after your input section.

Comment: Alright, Thank you guys very much! Never had any prior experience with console programming and that totally slipped my mind.